# How To replace the sequence \/ in android?

Tags: java, android

Issue in UI Is:

[image]

How to replace the sequence `\/` in android?

I Use below replace method but it show invalid escape sequences.

```
tempLabelForListView[i].replaceAll("\/", "")
```

Comment: try `tempLabelForListView[i].replaceAll("\\\\/", "")` the "\" char is used to escape special chars (like \n means new line). the error you get means the compiler read "\/" as "try to escape "/" which it couldn't. the "\\\\/" sequence is read as "escape the char '\' and then find a '/' after that".

Comment: @Oren: `replaceAll()` takes a regex, to match one backslash you need four, not two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, which takes a `regex` as parameter. Rather, just use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, and you need to escape the `\` with another backslash. And you need to re-assign the replaced string to your target string, since string is immutable, and the replacement will not affect the current string, rather return a new string: -

```
tempLabelForListView[i] = tempLabelForListView[i].replace("\\/", "");
```

As for [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, since it takes a regex, you would need to escape the *backslash* twice. Once for `Java` and once for `regex`. So, you would need *4 backslashes* to make it work with `replaceAll`: -

```
tempLabelForListView[i] = tempLabelForListView[i].replaceAll("\\\\/", "");
```

But still, you don't need it here.